# asp.net application, autosend emails

Tags: asp.net

I have a little asp.net application that I have hosted on remote server.  This application is supposed to send email notification (through gamail server) on a certain time set by user.

My question is, is there any way to achieve this goal as the user shall open the application via browser, set notification and close the browser.  Does application on server still keeps running?

Please advise how to achieve this goal.
Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET is not designed to facilitate this.  It is possible with some extended running times etc, but it would be better to run this as a service on the host machine.

Comment: I have created the Windows service, but how to host it?

Comment: You need access to the server itself to install services. See the install a windows service - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx - for details.

Comment: so what else do you recommend to make a notification application (web based, asp.net) which could check time against system time and send email, if time has reached?\

Comment: Like I have mentioned earlier, web applications are not designed for this.  If this absolutely has to be a web based application, then you need another method of triggering the web request.  You can do this by creating a desktop application to run on an independent machine that polls for a web page periodically.  This web page can then check against the system time, and do whatever is required.  In essence you are automating the page loads.  Not Ideal, but is should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the time is variable I would recommend writing a windows service which checks the current time at regular intervals against the set time from the website. This service will do nothing but fire off your emails which keeps your website completely independent.

I did something similar in the past where I had to send email/SMS notifications at various times, just be wary about how you check the time. The user will be setting *local* time which means if you are storing your dates in UTC format (which you should be) you may need to convert the timestamp back to users local timezone before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write Console application and add it in Schedule Task (if you want it to run after intervals), which is more trusted way of doing it.

Comment: The time is variable though, whenever the user changes the time it would mean updating the scheduled task, don't think that's possible using ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered that we only need to add Global.asax file (right click project in server explorer and Add New Item>> Add Global Application)
Just put your email code in the file.  When hosted, it runs through IIS, even though browser is closed.